# Consecutive find/replace with regexp

Tags: php, regex

Say I want to erase any quote from this string, and then replace spaces with '&', in php. I could easily do with 2 consecutive preg_replace or the like, but how to do it in only 1 passage?

```
" columns="4" link="file" ids="280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288""
```

to:

```
columns=4&link=file&ids=280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work fine:

```
$string = 'columns="4" link="file" ids="280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288"';
$replaced = str_replace([' ', '"'], ['&', ''], $string);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/gHHMp